# Generics List Interface

Tags: java

The List interface is the following:

```
public interface List<E>{
public boolean add(Object e);
public boolean remove(Object e);
public boolean contains(Object e);
...etc
```

Why aren't the add, remove and contains methods written like the following?

```
public boolean add(E e)
public boolean remove(E e)
public boolean contains(E e)
```

Comment: Its part of slide I was going over in my compsci class. I'd imagine that it should be the same interface used in the java api though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The add method is [add(E e)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#add%28E%29), so all is right with the world in that respect.

The [remove(Object o)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove%28java.lang.Object%29) and [contains(Object o)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains%28java.lang.Object%29) methods will operate based on `o.equals(e)`.  This allows you to do some tricky things with special-purpose comparison objects that aren't necessarily the type of object that are in the collection.

```
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList(20, 30, 40, 50, 100);
boolean moreThan60 = list.contains(new Object() {
    public boolean equals(Object rhs) {
        return ((Integer)rhs) > 60;
    }
});
System.out.println("moreThan60 = " + moreThan60);
```

Not that this is always recommended, or even a best practice.  But it is a neat trick.

Comment: I am really quite sure that is not the reason! If you read the API docs, that sort of hack isn't guaranteed to work.

Answer (score 1):

Backwards compatibility.

This way, you can still run java < 1.5 code with java1.5

So if you have some legacy code that is something like this

```
List list = //your favorite implementation
list.add(new Car());
list.add(new MandelbrotFractal());
```

universe wont implode;

Comment: so are you losing type safety because of this implementation?

Comment: No, you are gaining type safety with generics. But not so long ago, collections were not type safe. Suppose this scenario: You have a legacy project, in which you are adding new functionality. For the new features, you use up to date Java 1.X>5. But the old code base still has to run.

Comment: This would still compile fine. However, it would be more difficult to transform similar code (using one of the correctly identified methods) to use generics.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't correct.  The prototypes are:

```
boolean add(E e)
boolean contains(Object o) 
boolean remove(Object o)
```

If you correctly use the interface, you can never add a non-E to a List.  You can still call contains and remove with non-E's.  Technically, the List is allowed to throw a ClassCastException, but this is marked optional, and I don't know of any classes that do so.  It will probably just return false, with the List unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

If have an `ArrayList<String>` and assign it to `List<?> list`. Should I be able to ask `list.contains("it")`? It is very useful if I can.

Comment: So the parameters are Object for remove,add, and contain for cases where you were to use wildcards?

Comment: The parameter for add is *not* Object.